# Routing ip without proxy

Tags: windows, sockets, proxy, routes, ip

My goal is to save all ip address and urls that windows user generating and save them into local sql server.

I cant use proxy and browsers interfaces.
What other options do i Have?

Comment: More details would be useful here. How many machines? What's the network topology? Is installing software in the windows machines a option?

Comment: only one pc, yes installing software is what required - i am asking to know how to write the software to know how to implement this

Comment: That's a bit too broad for a stackoverflow question. I advise you too look into a packet sniffer, as I said below. Otherwise you'll need to be much more specific

Answer (score 0):

Running a sniffer seems like a good option, if it can handle the traffic.